# Making sure I have a timeout set while using watir to wait for page load

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

in watir I want to use `browser.wait()` to make sure I've waited until a page is loaded. But, what if the page is never going to load or is just taking a long time. I want to set a timeout. Do I do this with something like `browser.wait(8)`, specifying the number of seconds for a timeout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an update, Watir now deprecates a timeout value in favor of a timeout keyword, like so:

`Watir::Wait.until(timeout: 60) { browser.text.include? 'Hello' }`

Answer (score 8):

You can specify the Timeout value in parentheses after the wait statement:

```
Watir::Wait.until(60) { browser.text.include? 'Hello' }
Watir::Wait.until(60) { browser.div(:id => "mainDiv").exists? }
```

Comment: yeah. I checkout out the source here: https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb

Comment: Is the timeout in seconds ? docs not clear http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Wait

Comment: Yes, the timeout is in seconds.

Comment: Is there a way to set the timeout to essentially be forever? I'm looking to change a one-off assertion where it waits until a text change

Comment: @kmancusi that could lead to a very flaky test so I don't recommend it, but the timeout value defaults to nil so you could either not have a timeout or explicitly set it to nil for easier code review.  Go here for more: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Wait